# How can I pass a string parameter in Action?

Tags: c#, .net, action, producer-consumer

I have this Class:

```
public class PCQueue : IDisposable
{
  public delegate void OnFileAddDelegate(string file);
  public event OnFileAddDelegate OnFileAddEventHandler;
  BlockingCollection<Action> _taskQ = new BlockingCollection<Action>(); 
  public PCQueue (int workerCount)
  {
    // Create and start a separate Task for each consumer:
    for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
      Task.Factory.StartNew (Consume);
  }

  public void Dispose() { _taskQ.CompleteAdding(); }

  public void EnqueueTask (Action action) { _taskQ.Add (action); }

  void Consume()
  {
    // This sequence that we’re enumerating will block when no elements
    // are available and will end when CompleteAdding is called. 
    foreach (Action action in _taskQ.GetConsumingEnumerable())
      action();     // Perform task.
  }
}
```

And i have `string[]` that i want to add into my `Queue` and after that i want my `Consume()` get this files in order to processing.

```
string[] files;

PCQueue pq = new PCQueue(1);
foreach (string item in files)
    pq.EnqueueTask(item);
```

i have this error: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Action'

After i put file from my `Queue` i am check this file:

```
Checker checker = new Checker ();
string result = Checker.Check(my file from the Queue);
if (result != null && OnFileAddEventHandler != null)
    OnFileAddEventHandler(result);
```

And if this file is OK i fired up event to my form

Comment: Surely the queue should contain the data, not the tasks?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Nope, seems like the whole point is to process a collection of files with a predefined number of workers, so either the processing `Action<string>` is stored in the queue, or it is a queue of `Action`s.

Comment: @AndreySarafanov In that case you'd just create an array of tasks and use Parallel.Invoke() to start them, and use a BlockingCollection for the work items.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your intent right, you don't need to add a param to your `Action`, what you need is to change the way you call the `EnqueueTask` method.
For example if you want to enqueue the execution of a `ProcessFile(string filename)` method, you have to change your code to this:

```
foreach (string item in files)
{
    string filename = item;
    pq.EnqueueTask(() => ProcessFile(filename));
}
```

The reason to make the `filename` variable is to avoid closing over a `foreach` loop variable, which can be harmful depending on C# version you use, as further explained in [this](http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/) brilliant article.

UPD.: You seem to misunderstand what the `PCQueue` class does. Its job is not to store the filenames for you, but to store `Action`s that you want to do and then execute all of them via the `Consume()` method. That actions do not have to be related to files at all, they can be anything.

But i don't really thing that `PCQueue` is needed for your task. The way you use it, it is not more efficient that just looping over your files:

```
Checker checker = new Checker ();
foreach (string item in files) 
{
    string result = Checker.Check(my file from the Queue);
    if (result != null && OnFileAddEventHandler != null) 
    {
        OnFileAddEventHandler(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `Action<string[]>` ?

Comment: @Serv Maybe i understood the question the wrong way, but it seems like maya remetz wants to add a collection of `string`s to the `PCQueue ` class, so that each element in the `_taskQ ` is called with a corresponding parameter from that collection.

Comment: And when call to EnqueueTask what to do ? i have string[] arr and inside the foreach loop i just pass item and cannot convert string to Action<string>

Comment: Can i use string param = action.ToString(); ???

Comment: What's is ProcessFile ? the compiler cannot find it

Comment: @mayaremetz It is just a method name that i came up with. You want to do **something** with that files, right? That **something** is most likely a method that accepts the name of the file, so add that method to the queue, not the file name itself.

Comment: i am sorry but since i am new developer it's hard for me  to understand what to do, can i have an example ? (ProcessFile(string file) method added but still same error)

Comment: @mayaremetz Ok. What exactly do you want to do with your files? Do you parse them or process in any other way?

Comment: Check them via another class and then fired up event to my form (see my update)